# Tkinter - grid_bbox() how it works?

Tags: tkinter, grid

A simple question. In the Tk documents it says in 4.2. Other grid management methods:
"w.grid_bbox(0, 0, 1, 1) 
Returns a 4-tuple describing the bounding box of some or all of the grid system in widget w. The first two numbers returned are the x and y coordinates of the upper left corner of the area, and the second two numbers are the width and height."

but I can't seem to get anything in the example below. Please, what is wrong and how to use grid_bbox()?

```
from tkinter import *

#criar um objeto window
w = Tk()
w.title('Uso de grid_bbox')
l1 = Label(w, text='Título', font='Verdana 16', width="20",height="3", bg="red")
l1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
l2 = Label(w, text='Autor',font='Verdana 16', width="20",height="3", bg="yellow")
l2.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
l3 = Label(w, text='Título', font='Verdana 16', width="20",height="3", bg="red")
l3.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
l4 = Label(w, text='Autor',font='Verdana 16', width="20",height="3", bg="yellow")
l4.grid(row = 1, column = 0)


w.grid_bbox(0,0,1,1)

w.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until tkinter has had a chance to actually draw the widgets on the screen, it's impossible for it to compute coordinates since the final coordinates depend on many factors. You either need to wait until after `mainloop` has started, or force the window to be drawn by calling `w.update()` prior to calling `w.grid_bbox(0,0,1,1)`.

Of course, the other problem is that you're calling `grid_bbox` but then throwing away what it returns. If you're expecting to see something printed out you need to use the `print` function:

```
...
w.update()
print(w.grid_bbox(0,0,1,1))
w.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, nothing appeared on the console, still unanswered.

Comment: @JoaoCarlosAgostini: Well, you aren't printing anything to the console so I'm not sure why you think something should appear. Have you tried using the `print` function? (eg: `print(w.grid_bbox(0,0,1,1))`?

Comment: Yes, excuse me, with the various experiences I did, I ended up taking the print and didn't realize that I didn't repeat it. Thanks again, now it worked.